# Getting the highest word from the textfile

Tags: python-3.x

I am making an application related to Xbee and python, where i need to read the data from a textfile and then find out the maximum Router value from the textfile.
My textfile contains data like:

```
0013A20040C8316D - 0  0013A20040C8315B - 3  0013A20040C8316D - 1  0013A20041C8315B - 5 0013A20040C8316D - 4  0013A20045C8315B - 7
```

I tried this code:

```
 file= open("myFile.txt","r")
 dataRead= file.read()
 dataReadInString= str(dataRead)
 dataReadAfterRemovingString= dataReadInString.replace(" ","")
 #print(dataReadInString)
 print(dataReadAfterRemovingString)
```

```
Is there some way to get the value of 7(i.e, the highest number) from the textfile by reading the textfile. I am new to python . Please help.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look on [what is good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Show us what you hav tried and you will help you improving it

Comment: Please, can you edit your question with the code you have already written ?

Comment: I have tried to write the code. Please try and understand my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer as readable as possible. 
We will assume that your file as regular scheme: `id1 - name1  id2 - name2 ...`

Here the detail of the code:

```
file= open("myFile.txt","r")

# read file
dataReadInString = file.read()
# Remove line return
dataReadInString = dataReadInString.replace("\n", "")
print(dataReadInString)

# Create list for each element (id + name)
dataReadAfterRemovingString = dataReadInString.split("  ")
print(dataReadAfterRemovingString)

# New list that will have the ids
list_number = []

# Iterate for each element
for mot in dataReadAfterRemovingString:
    # Create list with [id, name]
    list_elt = mot.split(" - ")

    # Append to the list of id the current id
    list_number.append(list_elt[0])

# Display list of ID
print(list_number)
# ['0013A20040C8316D', '0013A20040C8315B', '0013A20040C8316D', '0013A20041C8315B', '0013A20045C8315B']
```

Hope that answer, any questions, ask in comments.

Comment: Thank you Sir. But i need the Highest number written after Router.  If it is required, i can print Router1 as only 1 in the textfile. I can written coordinator as 0 , if that can help in getting the problem solve. Please help. I am editing the question to help you understand my problem.